# Smtp server port open in SharePoint farm

Tags: 2016

We have new sp farm with 6 servers

- 2 web.
- 2 app.
- 2 dB.

Which servers should I open the smtp port on it? App Or web or both!

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SMTP server with the port 25 as a default one must be **reachable** from the WFE and Application servers in SharePoint farm.

> **Note:**
>
> - If you are using windows firewall, you should add an **inbound** rule for the SMTP port.
> - [You can test the opened port using Telnet Command](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/01/04/telnet-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-batch-file/)

**Finally,** you will need to aks the Exchange Administrator to create **Receiver Connector** to accept email connections from the SharePoint Servers over Port 25.

Answer (score 2):

Please check to which server you pointed mx records accordingly you need to open ports for that server The SMTP server with the port 25 as a default one must be reachable from the WFE and mostly for Application servers..by using telnet you can confirm whether the port is in open or not..for example open command line and type.
telnet localhost 25

If it is connected port in open for smtp